# Laravel Error Page After Create data using ajax and boostrap

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, laravel

So I'm trying create data using ajax and modal box from boostrap, but my pagination not using ajax, after created data Paginate and Table Has change by using render() in laravel.. after that I click Another page.. it making error Like This.. [Click Me for Look the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKWXA.png)

#### web.php

```
Route::prefix('ajaxCrud')->group(function () {
   Route::get('', 'ajaxCrudController@index')->name('crud.index');
   Route::post('add', 'ajaxCrudController@masuk')->name('crud.add');
});
```

#### Javascript / crudCustom.js

```
 $('#form-tambah').submit(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (results) {
            $('#tbody-row').html(results.template.table);
            $('#paginate').html(results.template.paginate);
            // ajaxLoad(results.url);
            history.pushState(null, null, results.url);
        }
    });   
});
```

#### AjaxCrudController.php

```
siswa::create([
            'name' => $req->name,
            'nomor' => $req->phone,
            'alamat'=> $req->address
        ]);

        $template = [
            'table' => view('ajaxCrud.ajax.table')->with(['data' => $siswa])->render(),
            'paginate' => view('ajaxCrud.ajax.paginate')->with(['data' => $siswa])->render()
        ];

        $response = [
            'status' => true,
            'template' => $template,
            'url'   => route('crud.index')
        ];
return response()->json($response);
```

#### index.blade.php

```
    @foreach ($data as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->nomor}}</td>
                <td>{{$item->alamat}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-success" href="#">Edit</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
```

#### Paginate

```
<div id="paginate">
    {{ $data->links() }}
</div>
```

### Modal

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('crud.add')}}" id="form-tambah">
            @csrf
            <span id="form_output"></span>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="nama">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                    <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="address">Address</label>
                    <textarea name="address" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
            </div>
            </form>
```